# помогите исправить код на питоне!

Tags: python

Я написала код на следующую задачу:

Даны действительные коэффициенты `a`, `b`, `c`, при этом `a`≠0. Решите квадратное уравнение `ax2+bx+c=0` и выведите все его корни.

Входные данные:

Вводятся три действительных числа.

Выходные данные:

Если уравнение имеет два корня, выведите два корня в порядке возрастания, если один корень — выведите одно число, если нет корней — не выводите ничего.

Примеры:

входные данные:

```
1
-1
-2
```

выходные данные:

```
-1 2
```

Код на предложенном в задаче тесте (`1, -1, -2`) выдает правильный ответ, но проверяющая система (информатикс) пишет, что на 4 из 12 тестов мой код выдает неверный ответ, помогите пожалуйста!!!
мой код:

```py
forest = float(input())
magic = float(input())
mushroom = float(input())
D = magic ** 2 - 4 * forest * mushroom
if D < 0:
    e = 1
elif D == 0:
    print(int((-magic)/2*forest))
elif D > 0:
    q = ((-magic) - (D**0.5))/2*forest
    w = ((-magic) + (D**0.5))/2*forest
    print(int(q), int(w))
```

Comment: Задача про квадратное уравнение, а в примере кода какие-то грибы, лес и магия. Лично я ничего не понял.

Comment: а зачем вы приводите q и w к целым числам?

Comment: `/(2*forest)` - думаю, скобки забыли

Comment: В каком формате проверяющая система ожидает ответ? Особенно если корней нет

Comment: если корней нет, то ничего выводить не нужно, если корня 2, то вывести в порядке возрастания

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача про поиск корней через дискриминант.

[image]

```py
a = float(input())
if a != 0:
    b = float(input())
    c = float(input())

    D = b**2 - 4*a*c

    if D > 0:
        x1 = (-b + D**(1/2))/(2*a)
        x2 = (-b - D**(1/2))/(2*a)
        if x1 < x2:
            print(x1, x2)
        else:
            print(x2, x1)        
    elif D == 0:
        x = -b/(2*a)
        print(x)
```

Comment: теперь неправильны 3 теста из 12

Comment: Изменил код, попробуй ещё раз, возможно это тесты на а != 0, в остальном код работал исправно

Comment: Видимо @andreymal прав, система ждёт что-то, и видимо не строковую переменную на случай если корней нет

Comment: подкорректировала вопрос, теперь там есть пробный тест с вводом и выводом, и критерии вывода

Comment: @Настя Проверь сейчас

Comment: @DiMithras Без конкретного ТЗ - результат будет ХЗ

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn, теперь код стал работать!!!

Comment: @Настя осталось добавить магии, лес и грибы )

Comment: Обязательно :Ъ )))

Answer (score 0):

Хм, немного запутался в переменных, но вот функция которую я писал для нахождения D
Попробуй воспользоваться ей (заменив переменные).

```python
def D(a,b,c):
    # D= b**2-4ac
    return (b**2)-(4*a*c)
```

И код D под твою задачу

```python
forest=float(input())
magic=float(input())
mushroom=float(input())
D= (magic ** 2) - (4 * forest * mushroom)
if D<0:
    e=1
elif D==0:
    print(float((-magic)/2*forest))
elif D>0:
    q=((-magic)-(D**0.5))/(2*forest)
    w=((-magic)+(D**0.5))/(2*forest)
    print(float(q), float(w))
```

P.S. Если не поможет, то сори( Я только недавно учу питон